# How to handle an Error correctly using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

when i want to send and Error using Javascript i do:

> throw new Error()

it works, but if i pass a number, example:

> throw new Error(500)

The result is:

> Error: 500

Where 'Error: ' is a string.

I have a function that handle this errors, this function must to know the code of the error, how to retrieve it? Do i have to parse the string? :-(

Thank you.

Comment: Does your question refer to Javascript in general or specifically to javascript running on ther server with node.js? If specifically about node.js, then I understand Raynos's answer below.  Otherwise, I can't see why making a slip with a try/catch block would shut down the server.  One the client side, I find throwing errors and catching them in try/catch blocks indispensable.

Answer (score 4):

If you throw an error that way, the text between parenthesis becomes the error message. You can also throw using [a custom Error Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error).

A very useful link: [The art of throwing JavaScript errors](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/03/03/the-art-of-throwing-javascript-errors/)

Answer (score 1):

Error instances have a `message` property, and that's what you should analyze, not what it prints into console (which is `Error.prototype.toString`).

Answer (score 1):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error - the error message is always a string. Even if you pass a number to it, it will be implicitly converted to a string.

`Error: 500` is the default string representation of an `Error` object - that's what you get if you convert this object to a string or call `error.toString()` directly. If you are interested in the error message you should access the message directly - `parseInt(error.message, 10)` should do.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend against throwing errors. Try catch is expensive and one slip up will mean your server shuts down.

I recommend you use the event approach, include eventemitters is most of your code.

That way you can just do `this.emit("error", new Error(500))`

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you're saying, extract the number using some RegExp?

Comment: Please see my answer above. It shows you can pass a number directly to throw and catch it as a number in the catch block

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to use the Error object.  You can just write `throw` followed by whatever you want to be caught by a catch block.
This little code snippet displays 500 in the alert box.

```
function throwError(msg){
    throw msg;
}
try{
    throwError(500);
}catch(e){
    alert(e);
}
```

If you test `e` with `typeof` it returns number.